# Detecting if Music (or other system) app was hidden on iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

With the new iOS version, users finally have the option to "delete" (actually hide) the stock apps they don't want, e.g. Stocks app or the Music App.

The problem with hiding the Music App is that then `MPMusicPlayerController` will have some issues when trying to play the device's music library (formally called iPod's library).

Calling `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"music://"]]` is the first thing that comes to mind, however it always returns YES, regardless of the Music App being installed or not.

How can we detect if the user has this app installed or not?